# How do you define a package-private *trait* in Scala?

Tags: scala, private, traits

In Java, it is possible to create package-private interfaces. Looking at them with javap, you see that they lack the "public" visibility.

In Scala, you can declare a trait as private[package] or protected[package], but looking at in with javap, it is still public.

So how do you create a package-private trait in Scala?

While the Scala compiler respects the visibility, my problem is that my API will probably be accessed from Java too, and I don't want to expose my internal implementation to Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to create Java package private modifiers using Scala.
However you can freely mix Java and Scala files in a Scala project. So the easiest solution is to create a Java class/interface and then extend it in Scala.

Comment: While John's answer was more "educational", you have provided a solution, probably the only one. Since most Scala projects are configured to compile Java too, this is reasonable.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is the answer to your question

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10488

> private has a subtly special status in the language specs of both
>   Scala and Java. Check out the discussion of private vs qualified
>   private in the Modifiers section of the SLS. In short, private is the
>   same as Java private, whereas private[foo] is not marked private in
>   the bytecode,  but simply involves a compile-time access check.

I don't believe you can truly make a trait package private once it is compiled into bytecode.

Comment: In your link, Martin Odersky himself says: "In short, private is the same as Java private, whereas private[foo] is not marked private in the bytecode, but simply involves a compile-time access check." Which is obviously in contradiction with the evidences I see from javap, but I think he was talking about members, constructors in this case, rather than classes/traits.

Comment: @Sebastien - fair enough. I didn't notice that all interface compiles into public interface. Regardless, I think Lex' solution is the best if you want your traits to be accessible from Java.